# Change request type "Options" to "POST"

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo-client

backend doesn't handle "Options" request type, so I should change it to "POST", but I can't find anything related this on docs or other sources

I searched any method for change method in api but there isn't

Comment: OPTIONS is for cors. configure cors properly on your backend

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in backend, it was related CORS